# Why is my NUnit tests not loading values from User settings config file?

Tags: c#, nunit, settings

Namespace 'AndroidAuto' contains code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.DeviceName = "droid";
        AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.DeviceType = "Android";
        AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.DeviceVersion = "5.0.1-234";
        AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.AppLocationPath = @"C:\WordPress.apk";
        AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.AppPackage = "org.wordpress.android";
        AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

        string[] my_args = { "/fixture=" + typeof(Tests), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location };

        int returnCode = NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(my_args);

        if (returnCode != 0)
            Console.Beep();

        Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Namespace 'AndroidAuto.WordPressTests' contains code:

```
        static MyDevice GetDeviceInfo()
        {
        MyDevice device = new MyDevice();
        device.Name = AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings.Default.DeviceName;
        device.Type = (PlatformType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PlatformType), Properties.Settings.Default.DeviceType);
        device.Version = Properties.Settings.Default.DeviceVersion;
        device.NoReset = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NoReset"]);
        device.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommandTimeout"]);
        device.AppLocationPath = Properties.Settings.Default.AppLocationPath;
        device.AppPackage = Properties.Settings.Default.AppPackage;

        return device;
        }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        MyDevice device = GetDeviceInfo();
    }
```

But, none of the user settings are being read. They return as "". What am i missing?

App.config file contains:

`<userSettings>
    <AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="DeviceName" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="DeviceType" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="DeviceVersion" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="AppLocationPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="AppPackage" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </AndroidAuto.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>`

The app.config is in the test project.

Comment: The app.config that you have mentioned is it from the test project?

Comment: yes it is in the test project.

Comment: maybe you must to set the value to the settings ````<setting name="DeviceName" serializeAs="String">      <value>Some value</value> </setting>````, I see that you set the values in the ````Main```` method and this method wasn't executed when you test it.